# What kind of Extruded Aluminum sections to replace main wooden frame on this DIY project?

Tags: wood, woodworking, frame, aluminum

> Please note, I am **not asking or suggesting Aluminum** for the **horizontal rods/ dowels** here. I am asking about the **Vertical frame**.

Since suggested **"Extruded Aluminum Section"**:

- Wondering if that will work?

  - Strength
  - Load capacity
  - Stiffness
- If so, what kind?

  - Extruded Section type - C, U, Rectangular, Hex.. lots of designs?

    - e.g. http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-x-3-Aluminum-Rectangle-Tube-6063-x-1-8-Wall-96-Long-/201466668412
    - http://www.jindalaluminium.com/jindal-ecatalogue.php
  - Thickness/ Strength

To balance strength, stiffness & weight, I was wanting to make the **Vertical FRAME** out of Extruded Aluminium Section as there are many kinds out there.

**Reference to DIY Woodworking Project for Home Fitness & Rehab:**

https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/lightest-woods-that-would-be-strong-stable-for-2-components-of-diy-wall-stall

> - **Horizontal: Wooden parallel bars/ rods/ dowels**
>
>   - Less thick than frame & probably need greater strength, rigidity & less flex
>   - Looking at certain wood types
> - **The Vertical Frame** holding them
>
>   - Will need to be made of thicker, wider & bigger pieces of wood, adding more to the weight, so a lighter wood would be better, maybe
>       plywood?

http://www.roymech.co.uk/Useful_Tables/Timber/Timber_Strength_Calcs.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you building something like this from scratch? Repairing something?

Comment: And I think the term you're after is "aluminum extrusion".

Comment: @isherwood - Thanks for that term. Plan to build this new, and it needs to be light - So steel and heavy wood is out.

Comment: I don't think she'd have any problem moving that one herself. If *you* do, you need to start with some more basic calisthenics ;) *"I think you're over thinking this."*

Comment: @Mazura - It's not just about moving it myself, but due to Urban Metro city space constraints it'll be mountable/ removeable; maybe even disassemble-able. This will be built only once - So I'd like to do it without any "I wish I'd researched/ though of that" :) And I appreciate all the wisdom of people here.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: You are looking for a [2x6 aluminum](http://www.onlinemetals.com/merchant.cfm?pid=13538&step=4&id=1269&gclid=CKzzg_zv68sCFYomhgod-NcJbQ) tube. This should be pretty much have the same physical properties as a pine 2x6 (which looks like what you have in the lower picture). In the upper picture, it looks like two 2x2s that are sandwiched together. I would think that a single 2x4 tube would be fine to replace that, unless it needs that sandwich arrangement.
[image]

Edit2: I bars are much more commonly used in metal working (for providing load bearing support). So, I found some load calculations for I beams, and did a little physics (maybe I should have pursued a physics career). It looks like the beams need to support about 425 lbs. See the pic below.
[image]

[image]

Edit- After some debate, I have added the calculation for torque, using 80kgs (only 176.4 lbs) for the weight. The torque is most simply and accurately found by adding the two forces (pulling hands and pushing feet) which would be separated by about 1 ft from a hypothetical pivot point (necessary for torque calculations). The formula for torque (mentioned in comments/discussion below) is T=FxLxSinA. The image below provides a clear description of the calculation. Please note that rounding errors involved with multiple calculations are never better than an elegant approach. The elegant approach is to realize that the hands and feet are 2 ft apart, so the length to the pivot is 1 ft, and the total torque (force) is (120kg+120kg)∙ft. Torque is (pretty much always) expressed in either english (529.2ft∙lb) or metric (717N∙M)... not met-lish (240kg∙ft); but it really doesn't matter, because it's the same number. **Nobody can disagree with math.** Whether or not torque is relevant to your search for aluminum beams is more of an opinion... but I'm pretty sure that most engineers would agree that the load bearing specifications for aluminum beams are the most suitable criterion for your project because the torque-force will necessarly be converted to the push and pull (the perpendicular, load bearing) force. So the force on the beams (for a 200 lb person) would be about 300 lbs through the narrowest part (the most important consideration for beam failure)... but the force on the bars (important, in my humbe opinion) could be a bit more (like 424 lbs).
[image]

Comment: Typical build of Stall Bars is wood frame based, and few steel builds out there, but both are heavy. I'd like to know if I have to go Aluminium to make it lighter, what kind/ size/ thickness would I need to go to replace the wood.

Comment: I am not considering for the rods to be Aluminium. Only the vertical main frame to decrease weight.

Comment: @AlexS - One 8' piece costs ~$150 and weighs ~35 pounds, which weighs more than a [pressure treated 2x6: 26lbs](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/green-kiln-dried-pressure-treated-lumber-weights-d_1860.html) (kiln dried: 16lbs). Plus one however, for answering the question as asked.

Comment: @Mazura - Wouldn't a hollow/ extruded Al section be lighter than that wood you pointed out? PS: Variety of cross sectional designs if there's something with better structural strength than border rectangular  http://www.jindalaluminium.com/jindal-ecatalogue.php

Comment: @Ben - Thanks for the changed, enhanced & improved answer. I love the physics you've added and will read through it more carefully and update my question with some more loading info - Unless there's a better SE to address that? PS: I will pull out my physicas/ engg. old books/ notes so I better absorb what you've written - You Rock sir :)

Comment: @Ben - Also, if you noticed in the 2 pics - the "depth/ thickness" of the Frame Pillar section is different in each and they both follow a different "hole spoke" binding mechanism. Hope to lock that down this weekend.

Comment: @ben - i have to disagree with your math.  since T=FxLxSinA (where A=angle between arm and normal) an 80kg man  holding the bars in the way the photo shows, would only exert a total torque of 800N in the normal.  since we can assume he is essentially a rigid body in this system (arms under full tension, legs under full compression), the force would resolve into a 400N right load (pushing his feet into the wall) and a 400N left load (pulling his arms out from the wall)....

Comment: ...this means the total max lateral (perpendicular to longitudinal axis) load on the bar is around 41kg or 90lbs (assuming hands are located right at the centre of the bar).  even if you assume a safety factor of 3 (way too high for this - more likely 2), you are still only looking at about 180-270lbs.   this is static load only

Comment: @personal privacy advocate: This is a lever equation (not torque); L1 is the length from the center of mass to his feet, and L2 is length from his feet to his hands (his feet are a fulcrum). Also, I over-estimated his weight and the length to his center of mass. You said 80kg, I said 90.7kg (200 lbs). But, just for fun, his hands and feet could be considered a source of force around a hypothetical pivot point; since his hands and feet are 2' apart, this is a very easy calculation; the torque at the theoretical pivot would be 600 ftxlbs (300 pulling plus 300 pushing a 1' lever)!

Comment: @personal privacy advocate: also, for fun, if you consider his feet to be a pivot (glued to the rung), then the only force is gravity; at 90° sin=1, so the angle factor is just 1. Now depending on where you think his center of mass is, the length could be different. But I went for 36 inches (over-estimated). So the torque (if he didn't have hands) would be just about (80kg x 9.8m/s2) x 1.09yd/M = 854N∙M

Comment: yes - that would be pretty close to correct (longest arm means center of mass would be at maximum).  but math fun aside, the dynamics of the system would be that of a moment and countermoment body of equal and opposite magnitude - important for the op's purposes.

Comment: sorry, missed the first post altogether.  i disagree - this is most definitely a torque issue.  the lever is a part of all torque systems, but although there is no torque on the horizontal bars through their centerlines, the system is one of torque because the body has 2 contact points and not one, which is why the forces resolve into flexural loads perpendicular to the long axis of the bars.  this 2 point system must be resolved essentially as a question of overturning moment.  the use of a hypothetical pivot point is fun, but not useful.  this guy is looking for a real answer, not a fun one.

Comment: @personal privacy advocate Not torque. The bar under his feet is a fulcrum not a pivot being turned with torque. His feet are pushing into the wall, his hands pulling outward. To calculate the torque, you would create a hypothetical pivot between his hands and feet. Incidentally, 854 Newton-Meter (N∙m) = 629.87808 Foot-Pound (ft∙lb) which is pretty close to 600 found the correct way (without his feet glued to a rung).

Comment: i am not sure what you think torque is, so i guess we will have to just disagree and leave it there.

Comment: @BenWelborn - I posted a related question that might be interesting to you :) http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/position-of-max-load-a-human-could-exert-on-horizontal-rods-of-such-a-system

Answer (score 1):

outside of any opinion i have on the idea, my two cents would be:

vertical members out of solid 3/4" 6061-t6 drilled to take the transverse tubes or rods.  less costly than going to a rectangular tube due to the loads you look like you are applying and thus the need for heavy wall and tig welding of the tranverse tubes to the uprights.  if solid, you can drill and tap a single retention bold per horizontal connetion.

horizontal members (i assume approximately 1.5" od) from solid 6061-t4 or 7075-t6 heavy wall tubing.  the latter is very costly and hard to find, so i would just go solid - cheaper and much more available.  do not underestimate the loads you will be applying on a 36" span.  wood has a very high flexural memory that aluminum doesn't.  aluminum doesnt like to bend, and once it does, it likes going back even less - it will fatigue over time if you allow flex in it.  wood doesn't  have the same problem.  you could a much better result if you did in fiberglass tubing with far less mass required.

or

just do it in steel - far less cost, way stronger, but more weight

Comment: Typical build of Stall Bars is wood frame based, and few steel builds out there, but both are heavy. I'd like to know if I have to go Aluminium to make it lighter, what kind/ size/ thickness would I need to go to replace the wood.

Comment: I am not considering for the rods to be Aluminium. Only the vertical main frame to decrease weight. 

I was wanting to make the vertical FRAME out of Extruded Aluminium Section - There are many kinds out there

Comment: PS: Looked up FG - http://www.ebay.com/bhp/fiberglass-tube - Wondering what kind.. for the Vertical Frame?

Comment: check mcmaster.com first.  they have all types, shapes and sizes.  if you go extrusion for the aluminum, you will have to figure out how to mount the wood into it without having the extrusions walls saw through the wood over time.  maybe surface mount socket flanges?  why is weight so important?   the differences in weight between wood, alumimum  and steel are going to be wood heaviest, aluminum second (because of the rods section thickness) and then steel (thinner parts for the same strength).  hybrid systems will be different

Comment: fiberglass wont be for you due to the huge mass of the rods

Comment: @ppa - Do chime in on the wood vs steel statement. Wouldn't a hollow/ extruded Al section be lighter than Steel you pointed out? PS: Variety of cross sectional designs if there's something with better structural strength than border rectangular  http://www.jindalaluminium.com/jindal-ecatalogue.php

Comment: okay.  wood, steel and aluminum are all very different materials.  ulitmately, when designing a system, cross section of a material and its tensile strength are most critical to any design.  the youngs modulus (kind of like stiffness) of a material is a third factor (which is directly related to the first two).   however, in the real world, things don't have just static loads.  there are flexural issues, memory issues and resonance and other vibrational issues.  so yes - a hollow aluminum extrusion could be lighter than a steel one, but it may not be the best choice, as there may be reasons...

Comment: ...such as fatigue, loading cycles, etc. that make one or the other the better choice.  even within a material family, type of alloy, heat treatment, type of fabrication, etc make a huge difference.  thus, material A may have identical weight and density to material B, but hugely different physical characteristics (ie.  a tool steel like d2 correctly designed and heat treated could do the same job as mild steel in a given application with 80% less material in section area).  woods and composites are even more complex as they exhibit  huge anisotropic differences and fab techniques change...

Comment: ...their qualities enormously.  the real secret behind being an engineer is not just being able to build something strong enough to do the job.  its the ability to do it elegantly, with the least amount of cost vs. weight vs. complexity.  anyone can russian engineer stuff.  just make everything twice as big as necessary.  the real art is in minimizing all inputs to get the same resultant fulfillment of application parameters.  that is why all of those extrusion profiles exist - to solve someone's problem for some application as elegantly and as minimally as possible with the best cost vs mass

Comment: @ppa - I agree :) Finding the most elegant solution is the issue here. I'll plug in some more data from my end this weekend to get more specfic guidance